# soapclient not found in phpinfo

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, soap-client

I know the same question is exist but i do all of the answer but they aren't helpful for me.plz help
I change all of my php.ini and uncommented the extension=php_openssl.dll and extension=php_soap.dll my php.ini address is:

```
/home/mychanneladminbot/etc/php.ini
/home/mychanneladminbot/etc/php7.0/php.ini
/etc/php7ts/conf.d/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

also I install again the soapclient with:sudo apt-get install php7.0-soap and then i restart apache server.
and my php version is 7.1.9;
but there isn't soap section in phpinfo yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the wrong php.ini file. Those from `/etc/php/VERSION/` folder are for php-cli. The one used in apache server is different. Look into `/etc/php/VERSION/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: there isn't apache2 directory in /etc/php/7.0

Comment: my configuration file in php info is: /etc/php7ts  but there isn't php.ini file in this directory

Comment: Please add this piece of code `var_dump(php_ini_loaded_file());die();` to locate the file the proper php.ini. Add this somewhere in the same file you use to display phpinfo. Perhaps your apache is using some completely different php because of number of version you installed

Comment: my Loaded Configuration File in phpinfo is none.